# Deploying SQL Server in Kubernetes: context deadline exceeded while pulling mssql image attempt

Tags: sql-server, docker, kubernetes, minikube, docker-desktop

When I'm trying to run SQL Server in kubernetes with the `mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server` image in minikube cluster in several seconds I'm getting the following in logs:

```
Events:
  Type     Reason          Age                   From     Message
  ----     ------          ----                  ----     -------
  Normal   Pulling         38h (x77 over 47h)    kubelet  Pulling image "mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server"
  Normal   BackOff         38h (x1658 over 47h)  kubelet  Back-off pulling image "mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server"
  Warning  Failed          38h (x79 over 47h)    kubelet  Failed to pull image "mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = context deadline exceeded
```

Pulling and running the image in docker desktop works fine.

What I've already tried:

1. Specifying a tag like :2019-latest;
2. Specifying an imagePullPolicy like IfNotPresent or Never. Seems like even after pulling the image via powershell directly kubernetes doesn't see it locally (but docker does).

I suspect the reason is that the image is too large and kubernetes has too short timeout settings by default. But I'm a newbie with kubernetes and haven't checked this yet. At least, I don't see anything about it in SQL Server examples.

Here's the deployment.yaml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mssql-deployment
  namespace: mynamespace
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mssql
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mssql
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 10
      containers:
      - image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server
        name: mssql        
        env:
        - name: ACCEPT_EULA
          value: "Y"
        - name: SA_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mssql
              key: SA_PASSWORD
        ports:
        - containerPort: 1433
          name: mssql
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
        volumeMounts:
        - name: mssqldb
          mountPath: /var/opt/mssql
      volumes:
      - name: mssqldb
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: mysql-pv-claim
```

service.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mssql-deployment
  namespace: mynamespace
spec:
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 1433
      targetPort: 1433
  selector:
    app: mssql
  type: LoadBalancer
```

pvc.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: mysql-pv-claim
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
```

Could you, please, help me figure out what I'm doing wrong? Let me know if you need more details.

Thank you!

Comment: It's almost certain that your workstation is using an HTTP proxy but your minikube virtual machine was not configured to use it; golang has absolutely terrible error messages, but that one is usually either firewall rules or proxy, and yours smells like the proxy one

Comment: @mdaniel As far as I know, the only place where a proxy is used is when I do `kubectl proxy` to view kubernetes dashboard and it starts proxy on 127.0.0.1:8001.
How can I check your assumption?

Comment: @mdaniel Also I wanted to mention that it works fine when I try some other docker images from docker hub. Even private ones. So, if some images can be pulled does it mean that the reason is not a proxy?

Comment: @mdaniel I just tried to switch from minikube to docker-desktop context. Everything works there! What do you think I need to do to make minikube work, too?

Comment: I'd guess something like `minikube ssh docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server` because you want to see what the virtual machine can pull, not your local workstation

Comment: @mdaniel it works! Thanks! May be you know what I should do next time to automate pulling images like this? May be I need to do `minikube start` with some specific parameters? I'm running kubernetes locally on windows